# Как достать из строки данные JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, строки

У меня появилась потребность достать из строки данные. Собственно сама строка

> ltype=%D0%A3%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+1&goal=uznat_01_now&thanx=thanx1&phone=%2B7+(111)+111+11+11&action=send&formorder=form-0&action=send&formorder=form-0

надо достать данные следующие `%D0%A3%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+1, uznat_01_now, thanx, %2B7+(111)+111+11+11, send, form-0, form-0`
которые передаться в data

```
    function simpleform(id,data) {
        $.ajax({
           url:'index.php?'+data, 
           type: "POST",
           data:{ 
             action: 'send',
             //data : data,
           },
          success: function(data){
console.log(data);
          }
        });
      }
```

и передать постом эти данные

```
    data:{
                 action: 'send',
                 //data : data,
ltype : ltype,
goal : goal,
thanx : thanx,
phone : phone,
formorder : formorder

               },
```

как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать метод получения из строки, объекта со значениями

```
function getQueryParams(qs) {
    qs = qs.split('+').join(' ');

    var params = {},
        tokens,
        re = /[?&]?([^=]+)=([^&]*)/g;

    while (tokens = re.exec(qs)) {
        params[decodeURIComponent(tokens[1])] = decodeURIComponent(tokens[2]);
    }

    return params;
}
```

Чтобы получить значения нужно передать в метод строку с ссылкой.

```
var myQueries = getQueryParams(location.search);
console.log('=>', myQueries.ltype)
```

`location.search` возвращает строку с параметрами в адресной строке